# System crash after donating through paypal

Tags: system-installation, downloads

I just went on the site and donated the $15 for all services just after confirmation it was paid on paypal my system crashed. I never had the opportunity to download what I paid for and did not give any information as to who I was. So where do I go from here thanks for any help you can give me! Gardener

Comment: What were you trying to download exactly? Ubuntu? Ubuntu is free of charge, what you see there is the possibility to do a donation. But you don't have to pay to download Ubuntu...

Comment: Ubuntu is free of charge, you did not have to pay, and donations are voluntary.  Do as shown in DnrDevils answer. As for PayPal crash you might want to either contact them to see if it went through

Comment: @dobey This isn't a duplicate. The OP is not asking how to install Ubuntu, they are asking how to download it without paying, something that the other question does not address. (and something that is nowhere near as obvious as it should be)

Comment: @Seth The answer to the other question should very clearly include information suggesting to donate, and specify clearly how to download without donating, then. Or you suggest every step of that answer should be split out to answer separate questions?

Comment: thanks guys think i will bow out of this one have requested my donation back through pay pal

Answer (score 3):

First Ubuntu Thanks you for your donation!!! However it is free-ware (It is provided free of charge for personal use) You do not need to charge anything else just select this option when downloading! [image: Not Now Take me to the download]

See the "Not now, take me to the download"?

Comment: I wanted to donate i believe in what they are doing and plan on starting a community myself so was looking forward to connecting as much as possible just wanted to support what they do. Downloading what they offer for that donation was secondary thanks GZ

Comment: So now I go back pretend I did not donate and go to the download button?

Comment: Yes, I would simply re-download it

Comment: Please remember to click the ChecK MarK if this answered your question! ThankYou  ;-)